# Throw back custom response from WCF Schema Validator

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, service

I'm writing a service and have implemented the `IDispatchMessageInspector` class and have overridden the `AfterReceiveRequest` function.

What I actually want to do is not throw any exceptions if validation isn't working. I want to construct my own response and send that back.

How can I do this? I don't want to send back a SOAP message at all.

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
            {
                try
                {
                    ValidateMessage(ref request);
                }
                catch (FaultException e)
                {
                    throw new FaultException<CustomResponse>( new CustomResponse { Success = false, ErrorMessage = e.Message});

                }
                return null;
            }
```

It looks like I have to throw an exception back?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look into using  [BeforeSendReply](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.beforesendreply(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a message.

```
            void IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
            {
                try
                {
                    ValidateMessage(ref reply);                
                }
                catch (FaultException fault)
                {
                    // handle the fault and create the reply
                    // choose one of the CreateMessage overloads    
                    reply = Message.CreateMessage(reply.Version, "SOME MESSAGE");                    
                }
            }
```

See the following for additional overloads of CreateMessage.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.createmessage(v=vs.110).aspx